ETH stuck in Smart contract tried a few ways but they dont work
This is the contract address 0xa633c2fE4B4771085C1B0c2310011bE89B63D5Af
Please if anyone can help with this

0.2 eth reward if anyone can help recover this eth , thanks

transfer(address(this), balanceOf(msg.sender).mul(100).div(100));
Since this was in the contract, and i manually transferred tokens to the contract i am unable to call the opentrade function

are you the contract deployer?

From what I interpret the problem is that the owner have 0 token balance. The tokens were moved into the contract in a previous transaction. Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible for the owner to retrieve those token, and the contract can't be enabled without some tokens in the owner balance. The function manualSwap seems to do what you expect, move funds to the taxWallet, but it first tries to swap tokens for eth. That part wont work until uniswapV2Pair is initialized. Which is done at openTrading.
